# Problema de UnicodeError ao tentar salvar uma figura com texto latex no Matplotlib

Tags: python, pdf, latex, matplotlib

Fala pessoal. Estou com um problema para utilizar a biblioteca MatPlotLib. Antes da última atualização do Windows eu utilizava a biblioteca sem nenhum problema. Eu a utilizo basicamente para criar gráficos de funções e salvá-los em .pdf utilizando a formatação em Latex para o texto, abaixo segue um código como exemplo:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Data for plot
step = 0.001
x = np.arange(0, 2 + step, step)
y = x*x*np.cos(10*x)

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
 plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.figure(figsize=(19.2, 10.8))

plt.plot(x, y, lw=2)
plt.title(r'Function $f(x) = x^2 \cos(10x)$')
plt.savefig('plot.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Porém após a atualização meu antigo windows bugou e fui obrigado a formatar o pc, e agora não consigo mais utilizar o mesmo código acima e salvar as figuras em .pdf, o seguinte erro acontece:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dviread.py", line 1057, in find_tex_file
 return result.decode('ascii')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Utilizando o mesmo código sou capaz de salvar em outros formatos, a exemplo .png e .eps. Depois da formatação basicamente instalei os mesmos softwares que utilizava antes.

Ps. O código acima foi testado no Spyder 3.2.6 e no PyCharm 2018.1.3 com a versão 3.6.4 do Python. O Latex está funcionando perfeitamente. Utilizo o MikTex para a base Latex e o editor TexStudio.

Comment: Infelizmente saiu um espaço a mais na oitava linha do código. Desconsiderem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então depois de muito sofrer consegui resolver o problema.

Para usar o latex, a biblioteca matplotlib utiliza do path de registro para acessar a workplace do Miktex. Acontece que o nome de usuário que eu estava utilizando era Fábio, com o acento. Então quando a biblioteca tentava acessar o path encontrava um caminho, que quando era utilizado para exportar a figura, resultava no UnicodeDecodeError.

Então criei um outro usuário Fabio, exclui o antigo e reinstalei o Miktex. Após isso o erro cessou.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente o `plot.pdf` contém acentos, talvez se configurar no topo do documento:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
...
```

Se estiver executando via cmd executar antes de executar o teu script:

```
chcp 65001
```

---

Conforme o exemplo em https://matplotlib.org/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/unicode_demo.html

Para utf-8 talvez tenha que adicionar também:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals

import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
...
```

Comment: Guilherme muito obrigado pela resposta. Infelizmente a adição da configuração indicada não surtiu efeito.

Comment: @FábioNascentes tenta por isto no começo do script: `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, editei a resposta com um exemplo

Comment: Guilherme testado aqui e infelizmente não compilou.

Comment: @FábioNascentes mesmo erro `codec can't decode byte`?

Comment: Isso mesmo, desculpe-me esqueci de citar. Mesmo erro.

Comment: @FábioNascentes tenta assim, troque o `plt.rc('font', family='serif')` por `plt.rc('font', **{'sans-serif' : 'Arial', 'family' : 'sans-serif'})` e veja se tem efeito

Comment: Guilherme ainda não. Mesmo erro.